# Updating an Item in Core Data

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I am new to Core Data. I fetch few objects into an NSMutableArray. 
Now I want to update an object with objectID x.

My question is:
How do I get the objectId for an object?
and then how do I perform updates on that particular object? (eg: change 'Name' attribute and save)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You get the ID by calling `[myObject objectID]`. You can update and save a new value by calling your objects accessors like you would with any other object. Then to write the changes to the persistent store you do:

```
NSError *error;

   if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
      // Handle the error.
   }
```